After creating a product with a tag, I'm unable to filter by that tag immediately
I'm trying to write tests using the @shopify/shopify-api@11.5.0 library ()
I've encountered some strange behavior.
For example:

When I try to create a product with tags (one tag) and then request all products filtered by that tag, I get no results. Only after a while does the product appear in the response.

The same situation occurs when I update a product. Immediately after the update, when I request a list of products filtered by product `ID`, I receive no results. After a while, the product appears.
Here's my code examples:
await gqlClient.request(
  `mutation CreateProduct($input: ProductInput!) {
     productCreate(input: $input) {
        userErrors {
          field
          message
        }
      }
   }`,
 {
   variables: {
     input: {
       title: 'new test product',
       tags: ['test'],
      },
    },
  },
);

const products = await gqlClient.request(
  `query ListProducts($query: String, $after: String, $before: String, $first: Int, $last: Int, $reverse: Boolean, 
   $sortKey: ProductSortKeys, $savedSearchId: ID) {
      products(query: $query, after: $after, before: $before, first: $first, last: $last, reverse: $reverse, sortKey: $sortKey, 
      savedSearchId: $savedSearchId) {
         edges {
           node {
             id, 
             productType, 
             title, 
             createdAt, 
             publishedAt,
           }
         }
        pageInfo {
          startCursor, endCursor, hasNextPage, hasPreviousPage
        }
      }
    }
  `,
  {
   variables: {
     first: 10,
     query: 'tag:"test"',
   },
  },
);

I researched this issue and found tools/apps for Shopify that can resync data more frequently than Shopify does by default. But I can't remember exactly what it was, and is it possible to resync it by myself...

Question: is this a cache issue? If you were to make this API call via Postman (or similar), do the changes show immediately?
If so, I would dig into the caching side of this library and clarify that in your question.
If not, I recommend removing everything in your question related to TypeScript and node.js [and maybe even graphql], as they are unrelated to the issue. If you have unhelpful keywords, you'll be getting traffic to this question that is unable to help you with your question. We can see how many people come look and then don't answer, which will cause some to ignore it.

No it's not a cache issue. It rather shopify strange thing that everything work asynchronously and they need time to index changes also...
